how to retrieve a individual key value pair based on a condition in an array of key values using jolt transformation in apache nifi
Input -
{
  "tag": "[{\"tag_key\": 581, \"tag_name\": \"Carrier\", \"tag_type\": \"Simple\", \"charLimit\": \"50\", \"tag_value\": \"DCdff\", \"tag_data_type\": \"Text\"},{\"tag_key\": 841, \"tag_name\": \"TSO Group\", \"tag_type\": \"Simple\", \"charLimit\": \"100\", \"tag_value\": \"TSO Group\", \"tag_data_type\": \"Text\"}]"
}


Input contains multiple tag keys, We need to retrieve both key and value when the tag_name is "TSO Group", then we need that object array.
output:
{
  "tag_key": 841,
  "tag_name": "TSO Group",
  "tag_type": "Simple",
  "charLimit": "100",
  "tag_value": "TSO Group",
  "tag_data_type": "Text"
}

I tried to get the array object where the tag_name is "TSO Group", but i couldnt retrieve it as I am getting null values.

Does this answer your question? extract value from nested json in apache nifi. It's hard to hande by using Jolt, the suggested way is pretty simple and good.
